# sequence that converges in measure but not a.e

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Can I use the following sequence as an example of  convergence in measure but not a.e ?

If we let $f_{n}(x)=\chi_{[0,\frac{1}{2^n}]}$ then $f_{n}\to f$ in measure as if we take any $\varepsilon<1$ then $\mu(\{x\in X:|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|\ge\varepsilon\})=\frac{1}{2^n}\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ but we don't  have pointwise convergence $f_{n}\not\to 0$ as $f_{n}(0)=1$ $\forall n$

Comment: But $\{0\}$ is a null set, so that sequence converges almost everywhere to $0$. You need to let the interval where $f_n = 1$ slide over the interval to get something that doesn't converge almost everywhere.

Comment: It converges pointwise *almost everywhere*. An example of a sequence converging in measure but pointwise nowhere is $\chi_{[0,1]}$, $\chi_{[0,1/2]}$, $\chi_{[1/2,1]}$, $\chi_{[0,1/4]}$, $\chi_{[1/4,2/4]}$, $\ldots$.

Comment: actually there are examples here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_in_measure

Comment: @DanielFischer: Yes, I overlooked it.

Comment: @DavidMitra: Thank you , I will try the one you recommended.